# «Atendu min antaŭ la domo de mia pranepo»

Tags: meaning

Mi legis iun kiu uzis la jenan proverbon el la [proverbaro](http://www.robkeetlaer.nl/esperanto/proverbaro/proverbo_000126.htm):

> Atendu min antaŭ la domo de mia pranepo

Mi komprenas la vortojn sed ne la signifon. Ĉu iu povas klarigi?

Comment: Ho, interesa. Mi povus diveni plurajn eblecojn, sed mi vere ne scias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ĝi havas similan signifon kiel “en la tago de la Sanka Neniamo.” Tio estas, atendu longan tempon.